# Find string match to Oracle table using regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, match, oracle12c

I have an Oracle stored procedure on an Oracle 12c database that receives a company_name input. From that company_name, I need to find and flag Federal institutions.  To accomplish that, I have a table (TBL_FED_KEY) with one column (KEY_1) of keywords.  The table contains nearly 50 values like:

```
ARMY     
FEDERAL     
AIR FORCE     
VETERANS     
HOMELAND SECURITY     
INDIAN HOSPITAL     
WILL ROGERS
```

To give you an idea of the company_name string that could be passed through to the procedure, here are examples:

```
US Army - Munson  Health Center     
Federal Bureau of Prisons,BOP/DOJ-     
Hickam Air Force Base Pharmacy     
Minnesota Veterans Home Pharmacy     
P.H.S. Indian Hospital     
Will Rogers Health Center
```

What Oracle SQL can be used to match the incoming company_name against TBL_FED_KEY.KEY_1?  I've tried multiple variations of REGEXP_INSTR but I can't seem to get anything to work 100%.  Is REGEXP_INSTR even the best tool to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: So what you mean is basically that you receive a full name and you search for some keywords in `KEY_1` inside this parameter? I'm afraid the issue here is not related to Oracle or regular expressions, but mostly having a 1:1 "relationship". Will `'%' || KEY_1 || '%'` really map 1:1 with every possible parameter?

Comment: Since the strings to compare to are fixed strings, no REGEXP function is optimal; you can do everything with standard string functions and comparison operators, like INSTR and LIKE. (INSTR probably better than LIKE, if the KEY_1 keywords may contain underscore or percent symbol.) Question though - do you only need to know if the input string matches **at least one** of the key words and phrases? Or do you need to know how many, and/or which ones? The answer is important for an efficient solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `like`:

```
select f.*
from TBL_FED_KEY f
where lower(i.name) like '%' || lower(KEY_1) || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want case-insensitive match among those string. So, use `REGEXP_LIKE()` function with case-insensitive(`i`) option :

```
SELECT *
  FROM TBL_FED_KEY
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(company_name,key_1,'i')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the procedure is supposed to do after it "flags" the company as federal vs. not. I would instead write it as a function as shown below (but you can easily reuse most of the code in a procedure, if needed).

Then I illustrate how the function can be used directly in SQL. You can also use it in PL/SQL if needed, but in most cases you don't. Note - the same idea can be implemented **exclusively** in SQL, resulting in faster execution, since you don't need PL/SQL at all. Important - even in plain SQL, this should be implemented via a **semi** join, as I demonstrated, for faster execution.

**Setup**:

```
create table tbl_fed_key (key_1 varchar2(200));

insert into tbl_fed_key
  select 'ARMY'              from dual union all
  select 'FEDERAL'           from dual union all
  select 'AIR FORCE'         from dual union all
  select 'VETERANS'          from dual union all
  select 'HOMELAND SECURITY' from dual union all
  select 'INDIAN HOSPITAL'   from dual union all
  select 'WILL ROGERS'       from dual
;

commit;
```

**Function code**:

```
create or replace function is_federal_institution(company_name varchar2)
  return varchar
  deterministic
as
  is_fed varchar2(1);
begin
  select case when exists ( select key_1 
                            from   tbl_fed_key
                            where  instr(upper(company_name), upper(key_1)) > 0
                          )
              then 'Y' else 'N' end
    into is_fed
    from dual;
  return is_fed;
end;
/
```

**SQL test**:

```
with
  inputs (str) as (
    select 'Joe and Bob Army Supply Store' from dual union all
    select 'Mary Poppins Indian Hospital'  from dual union all
    select 'Bridge Association of NYC'     from dual union all
    select 'Will Rogers Garden'            from dual union all
    select 'First Federal Bank NA'         from dual
  )
select str, is_federal_institution(str) as is_federal
from   inputs
;

STR                            IS_FEDERAL
------------------------------ ----------
Joe and Bob Army Supply Store  Y         
Mary Poppins Indian Hospital   Y         
Bridge Association of NYC      N         
Will Rogers Garden             Y         
First Federal Bank NA          Y
```

As you can see, I threw in a few **false positives** - to illustrate the important fact that this "technological" solution is only partial. A human will still need to review the individual hits, if accuracy is important.